# Installing SciPy for Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin of QGIS?

Tags: qgis-plugins, installation, scipy

When I open QGIS, this message shows:

> Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin: Please, restart QGIS for
>   executing the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. Possible missing
>   dependecies: SciPy

When I try to reinstall or uninstall the plug in, or even only click on it, it always crashes. 
I have already reinstalled QGIS but didn't help.
I have OS X 10.8.5 and QGIS 2.14.8

I have to do a land cover change analysis for a project and wanted to use NDVI, I had all my hopes on this plug in.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this, thanks for your help! Why do I need scipy? I thought when I downloaded QGIS, that the package is complete, and then I can add plugins as needed?

Comment: Do you have to install more than GQIS and SCP to use SCP?

Comment: Hi I have the same issue when trying to install the semi automatic pluging. I did install al the required plugins from source and I also tried through the terminal but it continues to crash and this appears:Check Python Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib installation for the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin. I'm desperate. Any help?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/160082)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/plugin-installation2.html). Your error message states - "Possible missing dependencies: SciPy"

The SCP installation notes for Mac state:

> In addition, download and install the python modules Numpy, Scipy, and Matplotlib